# How to make default Password Reset functionality work in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm following this [Official NET Core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc) where I've also chosen the `Authentication mode` as `Individual User Accounts`. When I try to call `ResetPassword` **Get action** method inside the built-in `AccountController` from a link in the default `Index.cshtml` view below it, as expected, sends the `code` parameter to the action method as null. And, as a result, the default `error.cshtml` page is displayed instead of `ResetPassword.cshtml` view. **Question**: How do I call the `ResetPassword` Get action method so its input parameter `code` is not null?

**Snapshot of Index.cshtml** with Reset Password link:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Application uses</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Sample pages using ASP.NET Core MVC</li>
            <li><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518004">Bower</a> for managing client-side libraries</li>
            <li>Theming using <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398939">Bootstrap</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ResetPassword">Reset Password</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>How to</h2>
        <ul>
....
</div>
```

**ResetPassword Action method in AccountController**

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ResetPassword(string code = null)
{
    return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under normal use that action expects to have the code bound from the querystring. If you take a look at the ForgotPassword POST action, that has code (commented out by default) that can send a link to the user that includes their id and a uniquely generated code (token).

There's a link in that action to a MS page, which guides you further on setting it up. You can test by writing the callBackUrl to debug if you want, then when you follow that link to reset password it should contain a valid token.

The reset password action then accepts the code, which within Identity will be validated to ensure it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be providing a link to `ResetPassword` from your Index, but instead should be linking to `ForgottenPassword`. This action will then generate the code and send an email with the link to click. That link will take the user to the `ResetPassword` action with the code provided.